# Prove the following statement about Kruskal Algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees, discrete-optimization, directed-graphs

> Let $G$ be undirected graph, $G=(V,E)$. Consider an edge $e = (u,v) \in E$ that wasn't included in the solution obtained from applying Kruskal Algorithm to $G$. Prove that this edge isn't in any Minimimum Spanning Tree of $G$.

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: If there are ties in weights, the statement is just plain wrong.

Comment: Kruskal's algorithm is for undirected graphs.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I wrote it wrong, G is and undirected graph

Comment: Undirected graph with directed edges?